# I'd like to replacetokens 2 files on yml step

Tags: yaml, pipeline

I'm try to replace token to both of appsettings.json but I can't find the syntax to add multiple tragetFiles

I've tried this but it doesn't replace.

```
 - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
   displayName: 'Replace buildNumber in appsetting'
   inputs:
    targetFiles: -src/Project.WebApp/appsettings.json
                 -src/Project.WebApi/appsettings.json
    actionOnMissing: fail
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution already

```
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
   displayName: 'Replace buildNumber in appsetting'
   inputs:
    targetFiles: | 
     src/Project.WebApp/appsettings.json
     src/Project.WebApi/appsettings.json
    actionOnMissing: fail
```